# Remotely access log files with WMI

Tags: windows, logging, wmi

What kind of logs can I access with WMI? Is it just event logs or can I for instance somehow fetch my FTP server logs, Exchange Logs, IIS logs etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[WMI Log Files](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394564(VS.85).aspx) is a good start to read, FTP/Exchange/IIS do not seem to fall under this...

It just seems to be for event logs as far as I can see.